# How to use SSL encryption and achieve communication between the client and server of SignalR with C#

Tags: c#, ssl, signalr

I have one using C # The basic connection code for the SignalR client and server implemented by the Net Framework is as follows:

**Client**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;
namespace WinFormsClient
{
    public partial class FrmClient : Form
    {
        //Connection to a SignalR server
        HubConnection _signalRConnection;

        //Proxy object for a hub hosted on the SignalR server
        IHubProxy _hubProxy;
        private async Task connectAsync()
        {
            //Set Certificate callback
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ValidateServerCertificate;
            //Create a connection for the SignalR server
            _signalRConnection = new HubConnection("https://10.224.10.10:12316/signalr/SimpleHub/");
            _signalRConnection.StateChanged += HubConnection_StateChanged;
            _signalRConnection.Closed += HubConnection_Closed;

            //Get a proxy object that will be used to interact with the specific hub on the server
            //Ther may be many hubs hosted on the server, so provide the type name for the hub
            _hubProxy = _signalRConnection.CreateHubProxy("SimpleHub");

            //Reigster to the "AddMessage" callback method of the hub
            //This method is invoked by the hub
            _hubProxy.On<string, string>("AddMessage", (name, message) => writeToLog($"{name}:{message}"));            

            try
            {
                //Connect to the server
                await _signalRConnection.Start();

                //Send user name for this client, so we won't need to send it with every message
                await _hubProxy.Invoke("SetUserName", txtUserName.Text);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                writeToLog($"Error:{ex.Message}");
            }
        }
        private static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErros)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Server**

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WinFormsServer
{
    public partial class FrmServer : Form
    {
        private IDisposable _signalR;
        private void btnStartServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //Start SignalR server with the give URL address
                //Final server address will be "URL/signalr"
                //Startup.Configuration is called automatically
                _signalR = WebApp.Start<Startup>("https://localhost:12316");
                writeToLog($"Server started at:{txtUrl.Text}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}

using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;

namespace WinFormsServer
{
    class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            //CORS need to be enabled for calling SignalR service 
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            //Find and reigster SignalR hubs
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I deploy the client and server on the same machine and bind a self signed SSL certificate to the specified IP and ports through the following statement.
`Netsh http add sslcert ipport=10.224.10.10:12316 certificate=xxxx appid={xxxx}`

Then I tried to start the server and it ran normally.
When I try to start the client to connect to the server, I am prompted with the following error:

```
StatusCode:400, ReasonPhrase:'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.SteamContent, Headers:
{
    Connection: close
    Data: Mon, 20 Nov 2023 04:41:15 GMT
    Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
    Content-Length:334
    Content-Type:text/html; charset=us-ascii
}
```

I have imported the self signed certificate into the Personal and Trusted Root Certification Authorities of the MMS Console Root, as well as into the Local Computer and Current User.
I don't know why the client can't connect to the server. Can someone help me?

Besides, If I change the server-side URL to https://10.224.10.10:12316/ , will prompt that the server failed to start, Inner Exception HttpListenerException: Access is denied.
I added the service name and bound Port 12316 in the local Inbound Rules.
Do I need to configure anything else?

**11-21-2023 New Update**

I have found a solution.
By running the server side as Run As Administrator, I can use the Public IP to start the SignalR server.

I have a new issue.
I have configured the Inbound Rule, but I cannot access the SignalR server from other client machines. The client side uses the following url to request connection.
*https://public IP:12316/signalr/SimpleHub/*

The error response is
**An error occurred while sending the request.
SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.224.10.10:12316**

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.
By running the server side as Run As Administrator, I can use the Public IP to start the SignalR server.

Comment: If you have a new issue you should post a new question.  You cannot expect anyone to reply to this in the answers.